cannot create to database in laravel-excel
I'm using laravel-excel to import list product and save to database
but i got error when save
foreach() argument must be of type array|object, null given

here is my code save new product in database
public function collection(Collection $rows)
    {
        foreach ($rows as $row) {
            Product::create([
                'category_id' => $row['category_id'],
                'name' => $row['name'],
                'slug' => Str::slug($row['slug']),
                'price' => $row['price'],
                'discount' => $row['discount'],
                'quantity' => $row['quantity'],
                'special' => $row['special'],
                'published' => $row['published'],
                'description' => $row['description'],
            ]);
        }
    }

I also add fillable in my model
class Product extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $fillable = [
        'category_id',
        'slug',
        'name',
        'price',
        'discount',
        'quantity',
        'special',
        'description',
        'published',
    ];
}

Please help me and why it got error!!!

The problem is that Collection $rows returns null.That is why you are getting error.

To expand on @Subha's comment, the code currently posted has nothing to do with the actual issue. Please revise and post the actual code responsible for setting/initializing the variable you are passing to the function collection


please try to modify the collection method and put this code

public function collection(Collection $rows)
{
    foreach ($rows as $row) {
        if (is_null($row['category_id'])) {
            continue; // Skip empty rows
        }

        Product::create([
            'category_id' => $row['category_id'],
            'name' => $row['name'],
            'slug' => Str::slug($row['slug']),
            'price' => $row['price'],
            'discount' => $row['discount'],
            'quantity' => $row['quantity'],
            'special' => $row['special'],
            'published' => $row['published'],
            'description' => $row['description'],
        ]);
    }
}



make sure import excel library

use Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel;
Excel::import(new ProductsImport, 'products.xlsx');


How would this answer the question? OP is using the package laravel-excel not Maatwebsite\Excel\Facades\Excel

FYI: "Try this" is not an answer. Please explain how this actually would solve the issue and please don't use snippets for non-run-able code. (It doesn't because the problem is not in the posted code as pointed out in the comment section)
